# Async/Await for recursive API Calls

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await, promise

I am trying to collect all the ids from a paginated endpoint.
I want to wait for all the calls to finish but it seems to only finish the first call and return the data and a promise to the next call.

How can I wait for all the calls to return.

```
const getSelectAllIds = async (url) => {
  let response = await axios.post(url);
  if (response.status === 200 && response.data.next != null) {
    console.log(`calling: ${response.config.url}`);
    return [
      ...response.data.results,
      await getSelectAllIds(response.data.next)
    ];
  }
};

const someFunction = async (url, data) => {
  const selectedIds = await getSelectAllIds(url);
  return selectedIds;
};
```

Comment: Are you asking how you make it so that `someFunction()` or `getSelectAllIds()` does not return a promise?  If that's what you're asking, you can't.  All `async` functions return a promise.  That caller has to use `await` or `.then()` to get the value from the promise.

Comment: yeah, I want to make sure I collect all the data from the paginated pages, i.e. selectIds returns all data and not a promise. 
sounds like I can't use async/await for this then in that case

Comment: I think 1 issue is at least that if your result has 3 pages, you will only get 2 pages of data. The last page will be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `async` functions return a promise, always.  So both `getSelectAllIds()` and `someFunction()` will always return a promise.  That caller will have to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value from the promise.  You can't make them synchronously return the asynchronously retrieved value.  Javascript does not work that way.

That's how asynchronous coding works in nodejs.  You can't ever turn an asynchronous value into a synchronous value.  You have to use the asynchronous value using asynchronous mechanisms.  For promises, that means the caller has to use `await` of `.then()` to get the value.

```
getSelectAllIds(someUrl).then(allIDs => {
     console.log(allIDs);
}).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
});
```

Note, it's not clear what you expect your code to do if `response.status` is not 200.  And, it also looks like you're not collecting the data from the last page because you don't add the data into the array if there's no `data.next`.

Comment: yeah I have a lot of code pulled out cause I can't show anything but this is what I was looking for. I am confused though cause I thought `async/await` was a different way to write promises without `then`

Comment: @KyleCalica-St - `await` works great within an `async` function.  It suspends function execution until the promise resolves.  But the caller still gets an asynchronous promise back as soon as it hits the first `await`.    The `await` you have in here `return [ ...response.data.results, await getSelectAllIds(response.data.next)];` works and vastly simplifies your code.  That's how you use it.

Comment: but his already using `await`. so what is the problem?

Comment: @arminyahya - The problem is that the OP wants `getSelectAllIds()` to return the value, not return a promise.  But, `async` functions don't work that way and in fact, you never synchronously return a value that was retrieved asynchronously.  An asynchronous value has to be communicated back to the caller using asynchronous mechanisms (promises, callbacks, events, etc...).

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the explanation, I believe I am starting to understand this a lot more now.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```js
const getSelectAllIds = async (url) => {
  const response = await axios.post(url);
  if(!response.ok) throw new Error('HTTP error'); // lets not ignore these.
  return [
    ...response.data.results,
    ...(response.data.next ? await getSelectAllIds(response.data.next) : [])
  ];
}
```

Comment: This is excellent and so much simpler to understand. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

**async generators**

I'm going to suggest a different approach, using async generators. It's my hope that the benefits of this approach are self-evident -

```js
async function post (url)
{ const r = await axios.post(url)
  if (r.status == 200)
    return r.data   // <- resolve data
  else
    throw r         // <- reject
}

async function* getSelectAllIds (url)
{ if (url == null) return
  let { config, results, next } = await post(url) // <- get
  console.log(`calling: ${config.url}`)           // <- debug output
  yield *results                                  // <- yield each
  for await (const v of getSelectAllIds(next))    // <- recur
    yield v
}

async function someFunction (url)
{ const r = []                                    // <- empty result
  for await (const v of getSelectAllIds(url))     // <- simple iteration
    r.push(v)                                     // <- collect results
  return r                                        // <- return
}

// run and catch errors
someFunction("/my/url").then(console.log, console.error)
```

**demo**

I want to demonstrate this in a way that you can verify the results in your own browser. To do that, we'll make a fake `DB` -

```js
const DB =
  { "/1":
      { config: { url: "/1" }
      , results: [ "foo", "bar" ]
      , next: "/2"
      }
  , "/2":
      { config: { url: "/2" }
      , results: [ "cat", "dog" ]
      , next: "/3"
      }
  , "/3":
      { config: { url: "/3" }
      , results: [ "pea", "yam" ]
      , next: null
      }
  }
```

Next we need to make `FAKE` which is a stand-in for `axios.post` -

```js
async function FAKE (url)      // <- fake axios.post
{ await sleep (1000)           
  if (url in DB)
    return { status: 200, data: DB[url] } // <- found resource
  else
    return { status: 404, data: null }    // <- notfound resource
}
```

Which depends on a little `sleep` function, to simulate delay -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
```

To run the demo, we simply replace `axios.post` with our `FAKE` -

```js
async function post (url)
{ const r = await FAKE(url)    // <- fake axios.post
  if (r.status == 200)
    return r.data
  else
    throw r
}

someFunction("/1").then(console.log, console.error)
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
const sleep = ms =>            // <- sleep for demo
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

async function FAKE (url)
{ await sleep (1000)           // <- simulated delay
  if (url in DB)
    return { status: 200, data: DB[url] }
  else
    return { status: 404, data: null }
}

async function post (url)
{ const r = await FAKE(url)    // <- fake axios.post
  if (r.status == 200)
    return r.data
  else
    throw r
}

async function* getSelectAllIds (url)
{ if (url == null) return
  let { config, results, next } = await post(url)
  console.log(`calling: ${config.url}`)
  yield *results
  for await (const v of getSelectAllIds(next))
    yield v
}

async function someFunction (url)
{ const r = []
  for await (const v of getSelectAllIds(url))
    r.push(v)
  return r
}

const DB =
  {"/1":{config:{url:"/1"},results:[ "foo","bar" ],next:"/2"},"/2":{config:{url:"/2"},results:[ "cat","dog" ],next:"/3"},"/3":{config:{url:"/3"},results:[ "pea","yam" ],next:null}}

someFunction("/1").then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
calling: /1
calling: /2
calling: /3
=> [ "foo", "bar", "cat", "dog", "pea", "yam" ]
```

**without generators**

Should you choose not to use async generators, you can write a simple async function. One advantage to this approach is it skips the need for `someFunction` entirely, however it has the distinct disadvantage that it waits for *all* results before you can start using them -

```js
async function getSelectAllIds (url)
{ if (url == null) return []                            // <-
  let { config, results, next } = await post(url)
  console.log(`calling: ${config.url}`)
  return [ ...results, ...await getSelectAllIds(next) ] // <-
}
```

```
getSelectAllIds("/1").then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
calling: /1
calling: /2
calling: /3
=> [ "foo", "bar", "cat", "dog", "pea", "yam" ]
```

Compare this to the result of using async generators where we can use the results as they arrive asynchronously -

```js
async function someFunction (url)
{ for await (const v of getSelectAllIds(url)) // <- async generator
    console.log(v)
  return "done"
}

someFunction("/1").then(console.log, console.error)
```

```
calling: /1
foo
bar
calling: /2
cat
dog
calling: /3
pea
yam
done
```

Comment: does not work for my use case, I need to do what you suggested and wait for them all.  I have already accepted an answer and my issues with this project now are more of the relam of rxjs and Redux. BUT this was a great explanation and showcase of generators I will be saving this post for sure!

Comment: Kyle I'm happy you were able to gain something from the answer. The second portion _without generators_, does wait for all of them before returning the complete array of results. Have a nice day :D