# Awaited Promise Assignment/Passing vs Simply Awaiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

What is occurring when an assignment to an `await` *Promise* is used versus simply using `await` without assignment? Taking the code below:

```
const getSomething = async () => {
  let todos = null;
  await fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(
      (data) => {
        todos = data
      }
    );
  return todos;
};

const getSomethingElse = async () => {
  let todos = null;
  await fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(
      (data) => {
        todos = data
      }
    );
  return todos;
};

const doSomething = async () => {
  const somethingPromise = getSomething();
  const somethingElsePromise = getSomethingElse();
  const something = await somethingPromise;
  const somethingElse = await somethingElsePromise;

  console.log(something);
  console.log(somethingElse);
}

doSomething();
```

The output is

```
{ userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
{
  userId: 1,
  id: 2,
  title: 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui',
  completed: false
}
```

However, if we change our `doSomething()` function to simply `await` the two *Promises* as follows:

```
const doSomething = async () => {
  const somethingPromise = getSomething();
  const somethingElsePromise = getSomethingElse();

  await somethingPromise;
  await somethingElsePromise;
  
  console.log(somethingPromise);
  console.log(somethingElsePromise);
}
```

We get the output:

```
Promise {
  { userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
}
Promise {
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 2,
    title: 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui',
    completed: false
  }
}
```

Why are we seeing these wrapped in *Promises*?

To drive the point home, if we were to simply do this:

```
  const somethingPromise = getSomething();
  const somethingElsePromise = getSomethingElse();
  
  console.log(await somethingPromise);
  console.log(await somethingElsePromise);
```

We would get the original output of:

```
{ userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
{
  userId: 1,
  id: 2,
  title: 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui',
  completed: false
}
```

From which you can see that there are no wrapping *Promises*

In summary, I'm wanting to understand what happens to an '`awaited`' *Promise* when it is assigned to a variable or passed through a function (such as `console.log`) versus merely being '`awaited`' without assignment or argument-passing.

> EDIT Below I show the three versions of `doSomething()` and the differing outputs.

First Version:

```
const doSomething = async () => {
  const somethingPromise = getSomething();
  const somethingElsePromise = getSomethingElse();
  const something = await somethingPromise;
  const somethingElse = await somethingElsePromise;

  console.log(something);
  console.log(somethingElse);
}
```

Output

```
{ userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
{
  userId: 1,
  id: 2,
  title: 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui',
  completed: false
}
```

Second Version:

```
const doSomething = async () => {
  const somethingPromise = getSomething();
  const somethingElsePromise = getSomethingElse();

  console.log(somethingPromise);
  console.log(somethingElsePromise);
}
```

Output

```
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
```

Third Version:

```
const doSomething = async () => {
  const somethingPromise = getSomething();
  const somethingElsePromise = getSomethingElse();

  await somethingPromise;
  await somethingElsePromise;

  console.log(somethingPromise);
  console.log(somethingElsePromise);
}
```

Output:

```
Promise {
  { userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
}
Promise {
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 2,
    title: 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui',
    completed: false
  }
}
```

Comment: "*Why are we seeing these wrapped in Promises?*" because you never *unwrap* them. Promises are promises and remain so forever and ever. You can get the value out by `await`-ing the promise *and the result* would be the value. The alternative is the promise API by using `.then()`/`.finally()`.

Comment: Very similar to the question/answer I provided yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66113622/async-await-for-recursive-api-calls/66113884#66113884).  An `async` function ALWAYS returns a promise and the ONLY way to get the value out of that promise is for the caller to use `.then()` or `await` on the promise the `async` function returns.  The value you `return` from an `async` function just becomes the resolved value of the promise that the `async` function already returned.  More explanation in the previously mentioned answer.

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ, but my question is about understanding the difference between the two versions of the function doSomething() as relates to what happens to Promises when we merely await them vs assigning or passing them into a function like console.log().

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 but I'm really just looking to understand the difference between simply saying "await VariableName" vs "const x = await VariableName"

Comment: @MichaelCameron you have a receipt for a pizza - that's your promise. It *will arrive* and you *will have pizza* but you don't have any right now. You then `await` the pizza delivery with `await receipt`. You now look at the receipt - it's still a receipt, it's not a pizza. That's how promises work.

Comment: @MichaelCameron you aren't reading my comments.

Comment: @VLAZ OK I think you may have read my question before I edited it. I mis-typed the part where I said "to drive the point home" and used the two console.log() functions. I added the keyword "await" into both of them (if you look at my edit). Thank you for your answer, in that context.

Comment: @MichaelCameron I don't see how this conflicts with anything either jfriend00 or I have said. `await` will *unwrap* the promise into an actual value. That is the return value of the expression. If you `await` a promise (remember, a receipt) and then *look at the promise* (remember, still a receipt), then you still see a promise (again, a receipt). The *value* is the delivered pizza. If you never interact with that, you never eat it. It just stays there until your cleaning person (let's assume you have one) throws it in the bin. That's garbage collection.

Comment: The only difference between `const x = await fn()` and just `await fn()` is that in the first case you stored the resolved value of the promise that `fn()` returned and in the second case, you didn't save that value so you can't use it.  It's pretty much analogous to `const x = y()` vs. `y()`.

Comment: FYI, `await variableName` does nothing useful at all unless `variableName` is a promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 In my example 'variableName' would clearly be a promise. It would be 'somethingPromise' and 'somethingElsePromise'

Comment: I've updated my question with an edit showing three different behaviors. If anyone wants to take the time to explain the manifest differences here, please do so. For everyone else, thanks for you comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a distinction between a `Promise` and the value it holds.

```
let p = Promise.resolve(1);
await p;
```

The value the promise holds is 1. While `p` is the promise that has already resolved to `1`. If you were to print `p` as it is you would see something like this:

[image: Promise printed on Chrome DevTools]

The important thing to notice here is that the promise has resolved and it's fulfilled.

It's an important distinction here, so I'll show the alternative. A promise that is **NOT** resolved (therefore not fulfilled or rejected).

```
let f;
let p = new Promise((fulfill) => {
   f = fulfill;
});
```

If you were to print `p` you will see that the promise is not resolved.

[image: Promise printed on Chrome DevTools]

If I were to call `f` with a value I would then resolve `p` with that value.

```
f(1)
```

[image: Promise printed on Chrome DevTools]

Now it seems you are under the impression that `await` functions differently if you do not store the value and just `await` the promise.

```
let result = await p;
console.log(result);
```

Versus:

```
await p;
console.log(p);
```

The difference of course is that `await` will evaluate to the fulfilled value of the promise `p` (or it will throw if it's rejected). So `result` is not a promise. But `p` is still a promise and `await` will not do anything to `p` other than retrieving the value.

`await` does not mutate `p`, it won't make `p` to be `1`

Comment: Much appreciated!!! Does the part where you call `f()`, placing the *Promise* in the *fulfilled* state correspond, then, to the third version of the output of the `doSomething()` function in my quetsion?

Comment: Well, not quite. `f` or the value of the first parameter of the resolve executor in the promise constructor is the mechanism by which a promise is fulfilled to a specific value (which can be another promise). `await` will guarantee that the promise is resolved, where as `f` is the one which fulfills the promise (and therefore resolves it).

Comment: Though it is true that in both, your third scenario and the outcome of calling `f` in my example, the promise will have been resolved and most utilities that print promises (say like `console`) will print the fulfilled value as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version, you await the promise and assign the result from the await to a variable and log the variable.  This assigns the resolved value from the promise to your variable.  Your variable is NOT a promise, it's the resolved value.  So, you see the resolved value in the log.

In the second version, you are just logging the promise and the asynchronous operation behind the promise has not yet resolved so you see a pending promise.  Your variable just contains the promise.

In the third version, you assign the promise to two variables and you then await each one which allows both of the promises to resolve before you then log the promises again.  So, this time when you log the promises they are fulfilled and the internals of the promise know the value.

Keep in mind that just because the third version logs a promise with the value in it, that really doesn't mean anything for your code.  You can't get the value out of that promise without using `.then()` or `await` on the promise.  `console.log()` has privileged access to the internals of the promise that a Javascript programmer does not have.  If you want the value out of the promise, you have to use either of these two forms:

```
const x = await somePromise;
console.log(x);
```

or

```
somePromise.then(x => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

> In summary, I'm wanting to understand what happens to an 'awaited' Promise when it is assigned to a variable or passed through a function (such as console.log) versus merely being 'awaited' without assignment or argument-passing.

When you do this:

```
const x = await somePromise;
```

You are NOT assigning an awaited promise to your variable `x`.  That value is NOT a promise.  You are assigning the resolved value of the promise to your variable `x`.  It just contains a value now.  The promise is still in `somePromise` and it will have an internal state that contains the resolved value.  Your variable now contains just the resolved value.  The promise was not transformed.  Instead, the interpreter paused your function's execution until the promise resolved and then it grabbed the resolved value out of the promise and put that resolved value into your variable `x`, then resumed execution of the function.

Comment: OK, but specifically as regards the third version. Why is it wrapped in a Promise, the internals of which are known, as you said, whereas if I were to use await within the context of an assignment - such as in Version 1 - it would not be?

Comment: @MichaelCameron - In the third version, you're still JUST logging the promise.  It's still the same promise object that it always was.  It now has more state internal it because it's now resolved, but it's still the same promise it always was.  It's like doing `x = {greeting: "hello"}; console.log(x); x.greeting = "goodbye"; `console.log(x)`.  You're still just logging the same object and it's internals have changed.  FYI, a promise is JUST a Javascript object that has some private properties internal to it.  As a promise gets resolved, it's internal state changes, but it's still the object.

Comment: The difference between the second and third demonstrates two of the three _states_ a Promise object can hold. The _Pending_ state means the promise has not yet been resolved or rejected. Your third example simply shows the Promise object has been settled and has either been resolved or rejected.

Comment: That simply means the same thing as `await` without an assignment. It causes processing the pause within the `async` function until the Promise settles.

Comment: @MichaelCameron - `await` always returns the resolved value.  If you assign it to a variable, then you're saving that resolved value.  If you don't assign it to a variable, then you just didn't keep it.  The promise itself has the same state whether you assigned the `await` value to something or not.

Comment: You are welcome. We all think/perceive of this stuff differently.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Any chance you could put an answer up here?

Comment: @MichaelCameron - Also, keep in mind that `console.log()` is doing special logging for a promise.  It's not showing you everything that's in there.  There are lots of other things in there, like lists of registered listeners for `.then()` and `.catch()`.  Before the promise is resolved, this particular implementation of `console.log()` is choosing to just show you `Promise { <pending> }`.  Once the promise is resolved, it changes it's display to include the resolved value.  This is just the `console.log()` implementation.

Comment: @MichaelCameron - One more attempt at an explanation.  Neither the `await` itself or the assign of the value returned from the `await` changes the promise state.  Instead, the `await` causes a pause in function execution until the point at which the state of the promise has changed on its own and it is during that passage of time that the state of the promise object changes.  So, your three cases are 1) Examining only the resolved value after the promise has resolved.  2) Examining the promise before it has been resolved and 3) Examining the promise after it has been resolved.

Comment: @MichaelCameron - It is the `await` in 1) and 3) that causes you to be examining the state AFTER the promise has been resolved.  The assignment ONLY captures the resolved value after the promise has been resolved.  The `await` (whether there's an assignment from it or not) causes everything in the function to pause until the promise is resolved and then you can either examine the promise itself (as in 3) or you can examine just the resolved value that you assigned from `await` (as in 1).

Answer (score 1):

Promise objects can exist in only one of three states:

1. Pending
2. Fulfilled (Resolved)
3. Rejected

Using `async`/`await` allows us to pause the operations within the `async` function until the Promise being `await`'d has moved from the *Pending* state to the either the *Fulfilled* or *Rejected* state.

So in your first example, an assignment statement with an `await` pauses until the state changes. If the Promise is fulfilled, the left hand side of the assignment will be assigned the value returned from the fulfilled Promise.

The difference between the second and third also demonstrates two of the three states a Promise object can hold. The Pending state means the promise has not yet been resolved or rejected. Your third example simply shows the Promise object has been settled and has either been resolved or rejected.

As a side note, if the Promise is Rejected while using `async`/`await`, it will throw. So `await` calls should always be wrapped in `try`/`catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are we seeing these wrapped in Promises?

Because you're logging the variable holding the promise, not the result of the promise that was returned from the `await` expression.

> what happens to an 'awaited' Promise when it is assigned to a variable or passed through a function (such as `console.log`) versus merely being 'awaited'

Nothing happens to the promise. It stays a promise object, it doesn't "become" the result value. There's no magical transformation that would make `somethingPromise` refer to the result JSON object now.

What happens when you use the `await` operator is that the `.then()` method of the promise is called, which doesn't change the promise object at all but schedules a callback to run. Then the execution of the `async function` is suspended and only resumed once the callback was run, and the `await` expression evaluates to the result value that was passed to the callback as an argument. Whether you assign this value to a variable, pass it to a function, or just ignore it, is your choice.

The `await` operator does not return its right-hand side operand.

Comment: But does the `await` operator return its operand if it's assigned a place in memory, for some reason?

Comment: No, it does not return its operand. It waits for the promise and returns the promise's result - which is distinct from the promise object itself. There's no magic behind promises, they're just ordinary objects that could be implemented in userland.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense